# Rails Routing by mapping subdomain to path via database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

A seemlingly simple problem which I can't figure out how to deal with (in Rails 3.2): we would like to offer the possibility to
our users to define a subdomain and map incoming requests using that subdomain to a path partially retrieved from
the database. So for example, while www.example.com will go to our usual root path, a request to steve.example.com
would first look up "steve" in a datbase table that associates subdomains with ids, and if a match is found route
the request to, say, www.example.com/folders/36 (where 36 is the id associated with "steve"), and if no match is found
continue looking for other routes in routes.rb.

I have a working solution using redirect, which goes something like:

```
constraints :subdomain => /^(?!www).+/ do # a subdomain is used and different from www
  match '*path', :to  => redirect {|params, req|
    req_protocol=req.env['rack.url_scheme'] # e.g. "http"
    req_host=req.env['HTTP_HOST'] # e.g. "steve.example.local:3000"
    ...
    code to pick up "steve", do the lookup and return a suitable URL
   }
end
```

Now, I do NOT want to use redirects for two reasons: firstly the URL is then modified in the user's browser address bar,
and secondly browsers tend to cache the redirects (even with status set to 302 or 307) making such a solution less dynamic.

If I had had access to the request object in routes.rb, I could possibly had done something like

```
match '*path' => "folders##{index}", :constraints => {:subdomain => /^(?!www).+/ }
```

after having retrieved index from the database table using the subdomain, but the request object is not available.
(I could however probably manage the case when no association is found using the "Advanced Contstraints" as described in the
Rails guide, although I haven't tested that, knowing that it would only fix a tiny part of the problem).